# how can i display UIlabel in UItableview cell where UILabel containing the xml data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xml-parsing, uilabel

this is my parser section where i am getting the attribute and values from the xml file.now when it will parse the xml concurrently should show the attribute and its value in the table view cell one bye one.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{ 
//NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName); 
currentElement = [elementName copy]; 
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"ProductData"])
    {
    objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    productDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   }

} 
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{ 
//NSLog(@"found characters: %@ %@", currentElement,string);
if(!currentString){
    currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
[currentString appendString:string]; 
} 
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:   (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{ 
//NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName); 
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"])
{
    [productDict setObject:currentString forKey:@"id"];
    [self labelsetting:0];
    [currentString release],currentString = nil;

    return;
}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"productNumber"])
{
    [productDict setObject:currentString forKey:@"productNumber"];
    [self labelsetting:0];
    [currentString release],currentString = nil;
    return;
}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
{
    [productDict setObject:currentString forKey:@"name"];
    [self labelsetting:0];
    [currentString release],currentString = nil;
    return;
}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"dateCreated"])
{
    [productDict setObject:currentString forKey:@"dateCreated"];
    [self labelsetting:0];
    [currentString release],currentString = nil;
    return;
}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"])
{
    [productDict setObject:currentString forKey:@"image"];
    [self labelsetting:0];
    [currentString release],currentString = nil;
    return;
}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"ProductData"])
{
    [objectsArray addObject:productDict];

    [productDict release],productDict = nil;
}
[currentString release], currentString = nil;


}
```

below my tableview where i want to show the xml data.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    { 
return [objectsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];


}


productDict = [objectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *data = nil;
for (NSString *key in [productDict allKeys] ) {
   // [data stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@",key,[productDict objectForKey:key]];
    data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", key,[productDict objectForKey:key]];

    NSLog(@"data: %@",data);

}
cell.textLabel.text = data;

return cell;
[data release];
}
```

This the console of this view controller

```
2011-10-16 15:19:01.627 cmsCommander[1795:207] namestring: emon
2011-10-16 15:19:01.630 cmsCommander[1795:207] username: emon@test.com
2011-10-16 15:19:01.874 cmsCommander[1795:207] found file and started parsing
2011-10-16 15:19:01.877 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element id : 1
2011-10-16 15:19:01.879 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element productNumber :    a91cc0f4c7
2011-10-16 15:19:01.880 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element name : Product 1
2011-10-16 15:19:01.881 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element image :  5e928bbae358c93caedf6115fa7d178b.jpg
2011-10-16 15:19:01.882 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element dateCreated : 2011-10-06T16:08:45
2011-10-16 15:19:01.883 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element id : 2
2011-10-16 15:19:01.888 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element productNumber : d8287e2e51
2011-10-16 15:19:01.892 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element name : Product 2
2011-10-16 15:19:01.893 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element image : 8bbd8dfff3cdd28285d07810a4fe7c32.jpg
2011-10-16 15:19:01.895 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element dateCreated : 2011-10-06T16:08:45
2011-10-16 15:19:01.896 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element id : 3
2011-10-16 15:19:01.897 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element productNumber : 7931c08c22
2011-10-16 15:19:01.897 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element name : Product 3
2011-10-16 15:19:01.902 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element image : e19becad20d6f4378e37313c5dbdf070.jpg
2011-10-16 15:19:01.904 cmsCommander[1795:207] current Element dateCreated : 2011-10-06T16:08:45
2011-10-16 15:19:01.904 cmsCommander[1795:207] all done!
2011-10-16 15:19:01.906 cmsCommander[1795:207] The number of row in the object array:  1 
2011-10-16 15:19:01.909 cmsCommander[1795:207] data: name  Product 3
2011-10-16 15:19:01.910 cmsCommander[1795:207] data: id  3
2011-10-16 15:19:01.911 cmsCommander[1795:207] data: productNumber  7931c08c22
2011-10-16 15:19:01.912 cmsCommander[1795:207] data: image  e19becad20d6f4378e37313c5dbdf070.jpg
2011-10-16 15:19:01.913 cmsCommander[1795:207] data: **dateCreated  2011-10-06T16:08:45**
```

now i think you have got my question.

Comment: yar problem is not clear to me...why you r not using same(individual) cell to show  all the parsed data...did u load all the parsed data in the same array...i mean id,name and image in the same array ?

Comment: ok i am editing the question again and please help me.

Comment: i think this is not the best way to add label in the table. u can use cell.textlabel instead. beside in your labelsetting method you r just initializing/creating label but no specification of adding those(returning nothing).

Comment: it seems we are from the same origin...ami dhakay thaki...ekta kotha boli...apni question post korar somoy privacy maintain koren na...eta thik na...kichu privacy maintain kora valo...

Comment: @makboney thanks for your suggestion. next time i will remind it.now please try to solve that problem.ami jototuki bujlam apni onek kisu bujen onek din dhore kaj krsen i hope amr ei prob amr kase very easy so help me i hope you will not disappoint me...

Comment: apnar ki just cell e parsed data dekhate parle e hobe ?

Comment: yes, amk cell e parse kora data dekhalei hobe...apatoto eta holei cholbe...jodi apni chan then amr arekta link e jei question ta ase setate edit kre dite paren...but anyhow help me...ami actually problem tai e bujtesina...

Comment: okay...ami kichukkon pore niche answer er ekta thread chalu korchi...apni reply diyen...ami asha kori apni table add kora janen...
so na bujhle question korben...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
            return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
            return [objectsArray count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (currentCell == nil) {
                currentCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }
            NSMutableDictionary *productDict = [objectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *data = nil;
    for (NSString *key in [productDict allKeys] ) {
        [data stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",key,[dic objectForKey:key]];
    }
            currentCell.textLabel.text = data;

            return currentCell;
    }
```

Comment: same problem last attribute data is showing.but i want every attribute and its value will show at the tableview cell.

Comment: i have fully changed my post..now please tell me the answer.if any further question please don't hesitate..

Comment: i have edited my answer a bit...if you have any UI Prototype(UI sample) you can send it to me if it okay also the current table's snapshot...dont hesitate to do question...

Comment: boss data er value to all time null ase ami nslog diye dekhesilam.

Comment: i have change the code a little bit now i can get all the value i can see it console but still now it is showing in first cell... change code are..[see my code].

Comment: data string showing in the table cell,but last value of the  loop.i am also posting my console also

Comment: :here is the ultimate result [posted console]..you are write there is only one row is coming and its taking only data of last product and first cell is displaying the last data of the data string.

Comment: i have posted my console now let me know where is problem?